# Why app never calls the alternative layout I created?

Tags: android, layout, size, screen

My default layout only match with emulator Nexus 5x (large).
So I tried to add an alternative layout to fit normal and large screen sizes. 
But the app keeps displaying the same default layout on every screen size emulator. 
It behaves as if there was only one layout.
Thanks in advance.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/quizImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"></ImageView>
```

Comment: Please include the code where you try to use the alternative layout

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links

Comment: looks like you did something wrong.  But since you didn't show anything - good luck fixing it on your own

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't added those layout properly.
Try this way.

1. Right Click on your Layout >> New >> Layout resource file
2. File Name should be same as of your layout file name e.g. activity_login.xml
3. Double Click on **Size** from Available qualifiers:
4. Add the Screen Size you need. Click Okay
5. Copy Paste the code from XML file to newly created XML File
6. Set its constraints accordingly

Hope this Helps !!

Comment: Thank you Ali Ahmed for your answer but i did it this way, so I I'm afraid something went wrong somewhere else.